# Gathering and rendering common data

Tags: grails, groovy

What is the best / cleanest way to gather common data, such as data for a sidebar.  In my application I will only ever have two different sets of data, depending if a `User` is in a `Project` or not.

I am doing it like this at the minute :

```
def dashboard = {   
    def returnVal = getCommonSidebarContent()       
    returnVal << getCommonHeaderContent()
    returnVal << [
        //other data related to the main content of this particular page
        ]
    return returnVal
}
```

where the likes of the `getCommonSidebarContent()` will return a map of user's tasks and other data.

I know this is bad, its what I started off with, but as time went on I never got round to sorting it.  It starts to look messy with the `returnVal` statements in almost every controller method.

Comment: You should use services for this kind of stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a [filter](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/guide/single.html#filters) can help you:

```
class MyFilters {
    def filters = {
        all(controller: '*', action: '*') {
            after = { Map model ->
              model.myCommonProperty = ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Within a filter you can perform common operation before/after a request is processed (i.e. adding common data to your model). Within `all(controller: '*', action: '*')` you can define the actions that should be processed by a filter (in this case all actions in all controllers are processed).

An alternative way is using [beforeInterceptor](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/ref/Controllers/beforeInterceptor.html) in controllers. You can use this if you need  common actions in a single controller.

Comment: Thanks, this looks to be what I am after, Ill give it a go.  Will anything happen to controller actions that arent passing back a model, but instead they are redirecting, if I use the `all(controller:'*', action : '*')`?

Comment: I'am not sure but I think the `after` method should be also called in a redirect event.